# Changing Default Layer Switcher

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, cartography, bing-maps

[image]

How can I change layerswitcher properties(radio button) ? So I want to change just like drop down list ?

Comment: With Openlayers 3 drop down list for Bing Maps - http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/bing-maps.html?q=bing - view source show it is contained in a div.